# Joomla 3.7 - TinyMCE - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceSelection' of undefined

Tags: javascript, joomla, editor, tinymce-4

This error happend when an editors-xtd plugin use the function "jInsertEditorText" with TinyMCE.

With version >= Joomla 3.7.3 (from the update of TinyMCE to 4.5.7).

For information the function "jInsertEditorText" is right, but it's the "replaceSelection" called by "jInsertEditorText" in tinymce.min.js that generate this error.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after update with phocadownload button (Joomla 3.7.5, TinyMCE 4.5.7, Phoca Download 3.0.6), there is an error on the file `view.html.php`, in:

```
/administrator/components/com_phocadownload/views/phocadownloadlinkfile
```

at the bottom about on line 121

insert  this:

```
$this->assignRef('tmpl', $tmpl);
```

instead of:

```
$this->assignRef('tmpl', $this->t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. I fixed it this way:

```
jInsertEditorText(result, 'jform_articletext');
```

just replace that `$name` with `'jform_articletext'`

for me it works fine